# in my production file: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' vitejs

Tags: node.js, npm, vite, vitest

in vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import path from 'path'

export default defineConfig({
    build: {
        target: 'es2015',
        manifest: true,
        minify: true,
        reportCompressedSize: true,
        lib: {
            entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "main.js"),
            fileName: "main",
            formats: ["es", "cjs"],
        },
        rollupOptions: {
            external: [],
            output: {
                dir: 'dist'
            }
        },
    },
})
```

in file main.js

```
import functions from './functions'

export { functions }
```

in file functions.js

```
const isPrime = (n) => {
    for (let i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        if (n % i === 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
export default isPrime
```

in file package.json

```
{
  "name": "vite-project",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "vite": "^4.1.0"
  }
}
```

The idea is that this package can be used:

```
in the browser
main.isPrime(50)
 or 
import Main from 'main';
```

the error appears only in the production file /dist/main.js when I use it in the browser:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'`

Thank you for reading

I have changed this line in main.js file

```
// export { functions }
to 
window.functions = functions
```

but when i wanted to do this it didn't work

```
import Main from 'main';
```